# Keras import error: cannot import np_utils

Tags: numpy, keras

```
import keras
```

Runs in the following error. My python is installed with Anaconda and I have done pip install Tensorflow / Keras / Numpy

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-7-c74e2bd4ca71> in <module>()
----> 1 import keras

/Users/florianfontaine-papion/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/keras/__init__.py in <module>()
  1 from __future__ import absolute_import
  2 
----> 3 from . import utils
  4 from . import activations
  5 from . import applications

/Users/florianfontaine-papion/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py in <module>()
  1 from __future__ import absolute_import
----> 2 from . import np_utils
  3 from . import generic_utils
  4 from . import data_utils
  5 from . import io_utils

ImportError: cannot import name np_utils
```

Comment: Which version of Keras did you install? and what are the contents of the folder /Users/florianfontaine-papion/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/ ?

Answer (score -1):

First, check whether Keras is installed or not by running following command in terminal. If you are using python3, use python3 in place of python.

```
python -c 'import keras; print(keras.__version__)'
```

And if above command showing error do the following

1. Open terminal and type this

   ```
   anaconda-navigator
   ```
2. Go to **Environments**  tab present on left side
3. Select your destined environment
4. It will list all the packages installed. In first dropdown select **ALL** and in search bar type **keras**
5. It will list **keras** package. Select it and click **apply** at bottom
6. Done

Comment: The problem is not that Keras is not installed, but that it errors while importing. I don't see how your answer contributes to solving this problem.